# Does the digital version of Starcraft 2 include two guest passes?

Tags: starcraft-2

Does the digital (purchase) version come with 2 guest passes, as the box version does?

If yes, where I can find them to send to my friends?

Answer (score 3):

No. I didn't receive any guest passes with my digital version of StartCraft 2. I checked a day after my purchase.

Answer (score 1):

When you open up the game, you have an option to "play as guest". I think that if you downloaded this game onto other people's computer, they could "play as guest" for the same amount of time that would be allocated by a regular guest pass.