# Where are my Starcraft 2 guest passes?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the digital version of Starcraft 2 include two guest passes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/does-the-digital-version-of-starcraft-2-include-two-guest-passes)

I heard that when you buy StarCraft II you get 2 keys you can give to someone to play the game for 2 weeks. I bought the game as digital download in the Blizzard shop.

Comment: It's probably included with the Limited Edition

Comment: This is the same question i posted 1 week ago: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/does-the-digital-version-of-starcraft-2-include-two-guest-passes

And so far, everybody told me that no, the digital version don't have guest passes.

Comment: Also, anyone can download de started edition and play that for a while. When in a party, you would even upgrade automatically to the most recent version anyone in the party had. Don't know if they disabled this functionality, if that was like a promotion or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the guest passes (2 for WoW, 2 for SC2) only come with the boxed version.

Have you looked under your Battle.net "games" tab? If the digital version *did* have guest passes, they'd have to be associated with your battle.net account somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

well there are no guests passes for the digital download -.-